# How understand about struct typedef conbination in UEFI?

Tags: c, uefi

IN UefiSpec.h the `EFI_BOOTSERVICE` look like this:

```
///
/// EFI Boot Services Table.
///
typedef struct {
  ///
  /// The table header for the EFI Boot Services Table.
  ///
  EFI_TABLE_HEADER                Hdr;

  //
  // Task Priority Services
  //
  EFI_RAISE_TPL                   RaiseTPL;
  EFI_RESTORE_TPL                 RestoreTPL;

  //
  // Memory Services
  //
  EFI_ALLOCATE_PAGES              AllocatePages;
  EFI_FREE_PAGES                  FreePages;
  EFI_GET_MEMORY_MAP              GetMemoryMap;
  EFI_ALLOCATE_POOL               AllocatePool;
  EFI_FREE_POOL                   FreePool;
.
.
.
    } EFI_BOOT_SERVICES;
```

In EfiApi.h the `typedef` with `struct` is like this:

```
typedef
EFI_BOOTSERVICE
EFI_STATUS
(EFIAPI *EFI_SET_WATCHDOG_TIMER) (
  IN UINTN                    Timeout,
  IN UINT64                   WatchdogCode,
  IN UINTN                    DataSize,
  IN CHAR16                   *WatchdogData OPTIONAL
  );
```

so is this a define of `EFI_SET_WATCHDOG_TIMER` a EFIAPI's function pointer or `EFI_STATUS` function pointer?
How to understand about the `typedef`?

Answer (score 2):

You first code quotation is irrelevant as it typedefs `EFI_BOOT_SERVICES` (note the singular and an underscore missing in the second snippet.)

`EFI_SET_WATCHDOG_TIMER` is typedefed to a pointer-to-function but it is unclear from your post what it returns.

Comment: Besides the singular there is also an underscore missing in second snippet.